# wait_for reaction_add doesn't work in DM (Discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I'm making a Discord bot with discord.py, and I want to make users set something by using emote reactions. Like add the reactions under an embed, then wait for "reaction_add".

```py
emojis = ["⬅️", "➡️", "✅"]
# the embed is sent, and reactions are also added by the bot
try:
    msg, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add',
        timeout=30,
        check=lambda msg, user: (user == message.author) and (str(msg.emoji) in emojis)
        )
except:
    return
```

It works fine in server, but when in DM, the bot can't detect the reaction from the user. It worked fine for 'message' though. Is there anything wrong in my code, or the API just doesn't support it?

Comment: Have you enabled Intents?